# Istio does not forward Authorization header

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh

```
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "jwt-api"
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/12312312312312312312/v2.0"
    jwksUri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/12312312312312312312/discovery/v2.0/keys"
```

Does anyone has any clue about how to foward the Authorization header to the microservice?

Istio 1.7

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution reading the docs:

**forwardOriginalToken**: bool. If set to true, the orginal token will be kept for the ustream request. Default is false.

```
- issuer: 
  jwksUri:
  forwardOriginalToken: true
```